# Create enum with specific values from another enum

Tags: c#, winforms, enums

I want to create a subset enums list from `System.Windows.Forms.Keys`,  that only includes A-Z, 0-9, and F keys. Currently, I set the full list to a combo box on a winform:

`comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof (System.Windows.Forms.Keys));`

Is there a fast way to create this subset? My current workaround is to hardcode a list of acceptable keys:

```
private List<Keys> acceptableKeys = new List<Keys>
            {
                Keys.A,
                Keys.B, Keys.C, Keys.D, Keys.E, Keys.F, Keys.G, Keys.H, Keys.I, Keys.J, Keys.K, Keys.L, Keys.M,
                Keys.N, Keys.O, Keys.P, Keys.Q, Keys.R, Keys.S, etc....
            };
```

and use that as the `dataSource`.

Is there a better method to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to hardcode it you could try checking the `int` value of the enum and adding them to the list.

```
var enums = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys));

List<Keys> acceptableKeys = new List<Keys>();
foreach (var e in enums)
{
   int val = (int)e;
   //The boundaries represent A-Z, 0-9, F1 - F24 respectively
   if ((val >= 65 && val <= 90) || (val >= 48 && val <= 59) || (val >= 112 && val <= 135))
       acceptableKeys.Add((Keys)e);
}
```

This won't include numbers on the numpad but you can add that check if you want to include those as well.

Comment: Works perfectly! Good thinking. Thanks :)